# Where can I download Nemo FM without cinnamon deps for Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, offline, nemo

Everything I find tells me to use the PPA, which isn't possible for me atm since I don't yet have internet (and likely won't for a while) and this rooted phone can't teather or hotspot including through ADB.

So I need to download the packages/dependencies and transfer them to my PC to install them...

Where would I be able to find the packages I'm looking for??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this ["Nemo 3 file manager for Ubuntu" PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/nemo3) by “WebUpd8” team. According to the PPA description:

> Nemo file manager patched for Unity (**with no Cinnamon dependencies except cinnamon-l10n for translations**). Only use this PPA in Ubuntu. Don't use it in Linux Mint or if you use Cinnamon!

(emphasis mine)

You may add this PPA by running

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo3
```

or browse for packages [here](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/nemo3/+packages).

Answer (score 0):

> Where would I be able to find the packages I'm looking for??

Inside the PPA

> Everything I find tells me to use the PPA, which isn't possible for me atm since I don't yet have internet

Well you do need internet to download anything ...

> So I need to download the packages/dependencies and transfer them to my PC to install them...

- [github](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo)
- [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/nemo3?field.series_filter=zesty) has the [debian files](https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/nemo3/+packages).

> and this rooted phone can't teather or hotspot including through ADB.

That is weird: using a phone as a hotspot is always possible. It is a core feature of modern phones. Does not require a rooted phone either.

---

I would use a live usb session to create a Linux system. Use that to boot from it on a system that has internet, then download and install Nemo FM and then copy the files from /var/cache/apt/archives/
 to your other system.

Comment: ` using a phone as a hotspot is always possible. It is a core feature of modern phones.` Tell that to Straight Talk, I wish that were the case with their phones. If I had bought a phone with no service and applied for Straight Talk, I'd be fine. (it's absolute BS)

Comment: also, that's the nemo with the cinnamon dependencies.